# change dropdown using php

Tags: php, html

how to get the value of options using php on changing drop down value will get changes

```
<select name="product_care_type" id="product_care_type" class="form-control product_sub_category selection select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="1">sd</option>
    <option value="2">Testing</option>
    <option value="3">Static Furniture</option>
    <option value="4">Computer</option>
    <option value="" selected="selected">-Select Product Care-</option>
</select>
```

Comment: submit the form, you ll get

Answer (score 0):

To get value of options on change of select box, you have to use JQuery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#product_care_type").change(function(){

            var selectedVal = $("#product_care_type").val();

            alert("You have selected - " + selectedVal);

        });

    });

</script>
```

If you want to get the value using PHP then you will have to submit the form and then using `$_POST` or `$_GET` method(the method you have used for your form) you can get the selected option value as `$_POST['product_care_type']` or `$_GET['product_care_type']` or `$_REQUEST['product_care_type']`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected value from drop-down in following manner :-

```
$_POST['product_care_type']
```

The best way is to wrap the select tag inside a form

```
<form  id="frm1" action"" method="post"><select>.......</select></form>
```

Comment: without submiting the form

Answer (score 0):

Get the value by `onchange` event through jQuery and pass it to a AJAX function to your required .php file and you can access it over there.